# How to use node-mtr?

Tags: node.js, traceroute

I want to use mtr for measure some network host on nodejs and i found the wrapper [node-mtr](https://github.com/Kami/node-mtr). In `node-mtr` github i try to install with `npm install mtr` but after that i don't know how to use the `node-mtr`. I already searched how to use or example code but i didn't found that.

[image]

Anyone can show me how to use or give me an example code?

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
var mtr = require('mtr').Mtr;
var mtrTest = new mtr('127.0.0.1');

mtrTest.traceroute();

mtrTest.on('hop', function(hop) {
    console.log(hop);
});

mtrTest.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Results

```
{ ip: '127.0.0.1',
  hostname: null,
  number: 1,
  rtts:
   [ 0.087, 0.042, 0.098, 0.092, 0.035, 0.07, 0.068, 0.044, 0.07, 0.093 ] }
```